# c++ for loop and 2 dimension array

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to create a c++ program which can calculate the quantity of something sold in 3 years.

I want to do it with a 2 dimension array and a for loop(requirement for the practice question)

but somehow, I can't get the result I desire. There is some error among the calculation and the storage. Could you help me identify the error?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int quantity[3][12];
    int sum[3];
    int *p;
    p=sum;
    int total;
    int year=0;
    string months[12]={
        "January",
        "February",
        "March",
        "April",
        "May",
        "June",
        "July",
        "August",
        "September",
        "Octorber",
        "November",
        "December"
    };
    for (int i=0; i<12; i++) {
        cout<<"Enter the quantity sold in "<<months[i]<<endl;
        cin>>quantity[year][i];
        if(i==11&&year<3){
            year++;
            i=-1;
        }
    }
    year=0;
    for (int i=0; i<12; i++) {
        sum[year]+=quantity[year][i];
        if (i==11&&year<3) {
            i=(-1);
            year++;
        }
    }
    year=0;
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            cout<<"the information for year "<<(i+1)<<" is " <<endl;
            for (int i1=0; i1<12; i1++) {
                cout<<quantity[year][i1]<<endl;
            }
            cout<<"the sum of the "<< (i+1)<< " year: "<<sum[year]<<endl;
            total+=sum[year];
        }
    cout<<"the total amount sold in three year is "<<total<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *There is some error among the calculation and the storage.* is unclear. Specify the exact problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this section:

```
    year=0;
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            cout<<"the information for year "<<(i+1)<<" is " <<endl;
            for (int i1=0; i1<12; i1++) {
                cout<<quantity[year][i1]<<endl;
            }
            cout<<"the sum of the "<< (i+1)<< " year: "<<sum[year]<<endl;
            total+=sum[year];
        }
    cout<<"the total amount sold in three year is "<<total<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It looks like you think you're iterating year, while you are actually iterating i and i1. Why not use the same trick you have bee using instead of the i1 for loop?

```
if (i==11&&year<3) {
    i=(-1);
    year++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!!! I could use the same method but I was trying to apply different ways on solving this question, since it was for practice purpose. Thanks again!

Comment: Could you please click the checkmark by my solution, indicating this question is solved?